# My for loop keeps repeating the items being printed

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

I am scraping a webpage and trying to print out all the bullet points on the page, but my for loop keeps repeating it in a strange way which I can't quite figure out why.
This is the exact response I got for Tuesday.

```
Tuesday
 In Class Today:

Read Chapter 4
Annotations 
Book Study




Tuesday
 Read Chapter 4


Tuesday
 Annotations 


Tuesday
 Book Study


Tuesday
 Due Today:


Tuesday
 Homework for Next Class:

Study Stems
Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed




Tuesday
 Study Stems


Tuesday
 Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed
```

Here is the section of the html(I cant give the page itself because it is hidden behind a login)

```
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p>
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Monday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">No School</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Tuesday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Read Chapter 4</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations&nbsp;</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Book Study</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Wednesday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Notes&nbsp;</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">"There Will Come Soft Rains"&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Thursday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Practice</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Friday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my for loop,

```
page = open("page.html", 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for x in days:
    for day in soup.select('h2:-soup-contains('+x+')'):
        for item in day.find_next('li').find_all('li'):
            print(x+'\n', item.text+'\n\n')
```

If anyone could help me figure this out that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpreted your question in the way that you do not want to print duplicate entries. The reason for them is that the outer bullet points also include the child tags. In order to avoid them, you only print the first item for each tag:

```
page = open("page.html", 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for x in days:
    for day in soup.select('h2:-soup-contains('+x+')'):
        for item in day.find_next('li').find_all('li'):

            bullet_point = next(item.stripped_strings)
            print(bullet_point)
```

Output:

```
In Class Today:
Read Chapter 4
Annotations
Book Study
Due Today:
Homework for Next Class:
Study Stems
Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Cause question is missing an expected output, so this is only an example*

#### What happens?

Tuesday is printed over and over again, cause you put it in the second loop for the several tasks.

#### How to fix?

To print it only ones, put it in the loop for the days:

```
for day in ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']:
    print(day)
    for item in soup.select(f'h2:-soup-contains("{day}") + ul li li'):
        print(item.text)
    print('\n')
```

#### Example

```
html = '''<div class="show-content user_content clearfix enhanced" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h1 class="page-title" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 I Week 3</h1>   <div style="background-color: #184366; color: white; padding: 15px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"><span style="font-size: 30pt;" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 | Week 3: January 18th-21st</span></h2> </div> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Essential Questions</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">How does voice relate to the audience and purpose?</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">What techniques does the author use to get his/her point across and communicate?</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">How can technology be beneficial and/or detrimental to society?</span></li> </ul> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Objectives</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Analyze the concept of utopia/dystopia as presented in the novel</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Create a utopia to represent the ideas of the group and backed up with research</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Analyze expository/informational text&nbsp;</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Understand rhetorical devices and logical fallacies</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Interpret elements of media including television and digital graphics</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Create a TV newscast that organizes and presents research with certain purposes and audiences in mind</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Collaborate to create a professional product</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Explain author’s purpose and message within a text</span></li> </ul> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Monday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">No School</li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Tuesday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Read Chapter 4</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations&nbsp;</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Book Study</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Wednesday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Notes&nbsp;</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">"There Will Come Soft Rains"&nbsp;</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Thursday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Practice</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Friday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:</li> </ul> </li> </ul> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img style="float: left; max-width: 72px;" src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791827/download" alt="Left Arrow (1).png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791827" data-api-returntype="File" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><br data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;<a title="Unit 3 Overview" href="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/111538/pages/unit-3-overview" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/111538/pages/unit-3-overview" data-api-returntype="Page" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 Homepage</a></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;</p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><a title="Home" href="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/111538/pages/home" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/111538/pages/home" data-api-returntype="Page" data-uw-styling-context="true"><img style="float: left; max-width: 72px;" src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791834/download?wrap=1" alt="Home Black.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791834" data-api-returntype="File" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <br data-uw-styling-context="true">Course Homepage</a></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;</p>  </div> '''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

for day in ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']:
    print(day)
    for item in soup.select(f'h2:-soup-contains("{day}") + ul li li'):
        print(item.text)
    print('\n')
```

#### Output

```
Monday
No School


Tuesday
In Class Today:  Read Chapter 4 Annotations  Book Study  
Read Chapter 4
Annotations 
Book Study
Due Today:
Homework for Next Class:  Study Stems Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed  
Study Stems
Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed


Wednesday
In Class Today:  Subject Complement Notes  "There Will Come Soft Rains"   
Subject Complement Notes 
"There Will Come Soft Rains" 
Due Today:  Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4  
Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4
Homework for Next Class:  Study Stems   
Study Stems 


Thursday
In Class Today:  Subject Complement Practice TWCSR  
Subject Complement Practice
TWCSR
Due Today:
Homework for Next Class:  Study Stems   
Study Stems 


Friday
In Class Today:  Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)  
Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade
TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)
Due Today:
Homework for Next Class:
```